# Shoe-horning a tabbed CSS show/hide element where it did not exist before

Tags: css, html

I developed a CSS-based layout for a web application that has been locked down and awaiting back-end integration. The primary element on the page is a timer/clock.

As originally intended, the timer is just a timer and is very simple. It looks like this:

[image]

Now, the boss has asked me to make a pretty significant change to my design. They want 3 tabs to hang off the bottom of the clock. They did not want this before, so I didn't build any show/hide logic and I didn't build tabs under the clock either. I am also slightly concerned because the tabs are at the bottom of the clock - that seems like a point of curiosity but I am guessing it is not huge problem either. Clicking on any of the tabs needs to cause the tab that was just clicked on to have focus, and it would cover the black rounded rectangle and display information about the tab the user clicked on. It would cover the clock. I would describe their request as reasonable, but I wish I'd had this requirement when I was coding. I think it sounds like a relative of a show/hide toggle. This is how they want the tabs to look, and where they want the tabs to go:

[image]

The part I am getting stuck on is how to slipstream something like this into what I've already created for the clock. Effectively they need me to make that component much more interactive, as the tabs have quite a bit of functionality within them. There are 3 tabs that I envision needing, but the mockup only shows 2, and that's ok.

I've included a few images in this post and I hope it helps. I've spent nearly a week smashing my head against this and I am stuck. To sum it up, I need to introduce (or shoehorn) a show/hide component as part of a late-hour change.

I am decent with CSS/JS/Web dev, but this is my Achilles heel. By "this" I mean taking a part of the UI that I already created and making it behave totally differently. In this case a pretty simple timer needs to change and has to have tabs at the bottom of the clock that would cover the clock itself when clicked. I hope I was clear enough in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very simple way to resolve this, using JQuery (you can use Javascript on it's own, but this will make it easier for you, less writing).
The give an ID to the DIV where you have the HTML for the clock, move the entire HTML content into a declaration like this:

```
$("#myDivId").html("put all the HTML content here, don't worry with the size of it");
```

you just need to change the HTML based on what you want to display. For easier implementation you can create a variable for each different content options, like this:

```
var myFirstHtmlBlock = "<p>blah blah blah</p>";
var mySecondHtmlBlock = "<span>Anything else...</span>";
```

and then change the content using those variables:

```
$("#myDivId").html(mySecondHtmlBlock);
```

Just let me know if this sorted out your issue.